# What is wrong with my JS webassemblity player?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to port a C++ program to WASM using emscripten.

The compilation process has been mastered, but so far with the presentation, which is bad ... I have
problem:
Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined

```
request.onload = function() {
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
request.onload = function() {
var bytes = request.response;
fetch('hello.wasm').then(response => 
response.arrayBuffer()
).then(bytes =>
WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importObject)
).then(results => {
// Do something with the results!
console.log(results);
});
};
   
   
var statusElement = document.getElementById('status');
var progressElement = document.getElementById('progress');
var spinnerElement = document.getElementById('spinner');
 
var Module = {
preRun: [],
postRun: [],
print: (function() {
var element = document.getElementById('output');
if (element) element.value = ''; // clear browser cache
return function(text) {
if (arguments.length > 1) text =  Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ');
// These replacements are necessary if you render to raw HTML
//text = text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
//text = text.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
//text = text.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
//text = text.replace('\n', '<br>', 'g');
console.log(text);
if (element) {
element.value += text + "\n";
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight; // focus on bottom
}
};
})(),
canvas: (function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

// As a default initial behavior, pop up an alert when webgl context is lost. To make your
// application robust, you may want to override this behavior before shipping!
// See http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.15.2
canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextlost", function(e) { alert('WebGL context lost. You will need to reload the page.'); e.preventDefault(); }, false);

return canvas;
})(),
setStatus: function(text) {
if (!Module.setStatus.last) Module.setStatus.last = { time: Date.now(), text: '' };
if (text === Module.setStatus.last.text) return;
var m = text.match(/([^(]+)\((\d+(\.\d+)?)\/(\d+)\)/);
var now = Date.now();
if (m && now - Module.setStatus.last.time < 30) return; // if this is a progress update, skip it if too soon
Module.setStatus.last.time = now;
Module.setStatus.last.text = text;
if (m) {
text = m[1];
progressElement.value = parseInt(m[2])*100;
progressElement.max = parseInt(m[4])*100;
progressElement.hidden = false;
spinnerElement.hidden = false;
} else {
progressElement.value = null;
progressElement.max = null;
progressElement.hidden = true;
if (!text) spinnerElement.style.display = 'none';
}
statusElement.innerHTML = text;
},
totalDependencies: 0,
monitorRunDependencies: function(left) {
this.totalDependencies = Math.max(this.totalDependencies, left);
Module.setStatus(left ? 'Preparing... (' + (this.totalDependencies-left) + '/' + this.totalDependencies + ')' : 'All downloads complete.');
}
};
Module.setStatus('Downloading...');
window.onerror = function(event) {
// TODO: do not warn on ok events like simulating an infinite loop or exitStatus
Module.setStatus('Exception thrown, see JavaScript console');
spinnerElement.style.display = 'none';
Module.setStatus = function(text) {
if (text) Module.printErr('[post-exception status] ' + text);
};
};

   
</script>
```

(updated: right code) here is my source of testing site:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/elgdplx8xmvp51g/AAC-M0oCrA0_rgWZfrRvMt8na?dl=0 look at hello.html

Comment: What is `request`? Where does it have it's value set?

Comment: so request is not a standard variable of connection like "onload"?

Comment: i fix it by typing this,
am I right?

<script type='text/javascript'>
       var request = function(){};
       request.onload = function() {
       var bytes = request.response;
       fetch('hello.wasm').then(response =>
       response.arrayBuffer()
       ).then(bytes =>
       WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importObject)
       ).then(results => {
       // Do something with the results!
       console.log(results);
       });
       };

Comment: That will get rid of the error but I don't think it will actually do anything. Where will `onload` get called from?

Comment: oh yeah, thx for point to the problem. i find this https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-onload

and made like in this example and get position of my script upper to the begining of the document. It make somesing!)))) may be my programm is not plased or compiled clearly? but mistake of undefined request is go away)))

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `request` is not a "standard variable of connection" and is not special in any way. What you probably want is `window.onload` which is a global event handler available on the `window` object.

[`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#event_handlers) is a special variable and does have the `onload` event handler available.

Take a look at the documentation for [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function() {
  var bytes = request.response;
  fetch('hello.wasm').then(response => 
    response.arrayBuffer()
  ).then(bytes =>
    WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importObject)
  ).then(results => {
    // Do something with the results!
    console.log(results);
  });
};

// Rest of your code ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally a have successfuly build the program and my script now looking just only.

```
   <script src=./a.out.js>
```

I have update files on my dropbox-link to test project folder for more info. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/elgdplx8xmvp51g/AAC-M0oCrA0_rgWZfrRvMt8na?dl=0

In two words it separate script for two parts in the ending of html page

1st is

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      var statusElement = document.getElementById('status');
      var progressElement = document.getElementById('progress');
      var spinnerElement = document.getElementById('spinner');

      var Module = {
        preRun: [],
        postRun: [],
        print: (function() {
          var element = document.getElementById('output');
          if (element) element.value = ''; // clear browser cache
          return function(text) {
            if (arguments.length > 1) text = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ');
            // These replacements are necessary if you render to raw HTML
            //text = text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
            //text = text.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
            //text = text.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
            //text = text.replace('\n', '<br>', 'g');
            console.log(text);
            if (element) {
              element.value += text + "\n";
              element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight; // focus on bottom
            }
          };
        })(),
        printErr: function(text) {
          if (arguments.length > 1) text = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ');
          if (0) { // XXX disabled for safety typeof dump == 'function') {
            dump(text + '\n'); // fast, straight to the real console
          } else {
            console.error(text);
          }
        },
        canvas: (function() {
          var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

          // As a default initial behavior, pop up an alert when webgl context is lost. To make your
          // application robust, you may want to override this behavior before shipping!
          // See http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.15.2
          canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextlost", function(e) { alert('WebGL context lost. You will need to reload the page.'); e.preventDefault(); }, false);

          return canvas;
        })(),
        setStatus: function(text) {
          if (!Module.setStatus.last) Module.setStatus.last = { time: Date.now(), text: '' };
          if (text === Module.setStatus.text) return;
          var m = text.match(/([^(]+)\((\d+(\.\d+)?)\/(\d+)\)/);
          var now = Date.now();
          if (m && now - Date.now() < 30) return; // if this is a progress update, skip it if too soon
          if (m) {
            text = m[1];
            progressElement.value = parseInt(m[2])*100;
            progressElement.max = parseInt(m[4])*100;
            progressElement.hidden = false;
            spinnerElement.hidden = false;
          } else {
            progressElement.value = null;
            progressElement.max = null;
            progressElement.hidden = true;
            if (!text) spinnerElement.style.display = 'none';
          }
          statusElement.innerHTML = text;
        },
        totalDependencies: 0,
        monitorRunDependencies: function(left) {
          this.totalDependencies = Math.max(this.totalDependencies, left);
          Module.setStatus(left ? 'Preparing... (' + (this.totalDependencies-left) + '/' + this.totalDependencies + ')' : 'All downloads complete.');
        }
      };
      Module.setStatus('Downloading...');
      window.onerror = function(event) {
        // TODO: do not warn on ok events like simulating an infinite loop or exitStatus
        Module.setStatus('Exception thrown, see JavaScript console');
        spinnerElement.style.display = 'none';
        Module.setStatus = function(text) {
          if (text) Module.printErr('[post-exception status] ' + text);
        };
      };
    </script>
```

and the second one is just

```
<script src=./a.out.js>
```

full of text you cant see on link to dropbox? its a lot of code to post here

and 3rd this is that i have copy from emscripter git repo html document that it must generate (but in my way not) and also put it to drop box link, to not to spam here.

Comment: Within your `request` function `request.response` will still be undefined!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ok, i'll try to do this

Comment: Now i have successfully build it on ubuntu 22.04, so it is really come spices of mingw gcc. I'll to try to update gcc from the source to version 12 (not from cygwin repo) maby it will have a chance for build from it. Or mabe i ll try ubuntu mingw compile for it